# Handlebars helper interpets string as integer

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebars.net

**Context**

In handlebars, I want to compare two values and print X or Y depending if they are equal or not.
I successfully registered a comparison helper:

```
private static string GetArgumentValue(object argument)
{   
   if (argument.GetType().Name == "UndefinedBindingResult")
   {   
      return (string) argument.GetType().GetField("Value").GetValue(argument);
   }
    
   return argument.ToString();
}
    
public void RegisterHelper()
{
   Handlebars.RegisterHelper("ifCond", (output, context, arguments) =>
   {
      var value1 = GetArgumentValue(arguments[0]);
      var operation = GetArgumentValue(arguments[1]);
      var value2 = GetArgumentValue(arguments[2]);
      var returnValue1 = GetArgumentValue(arguments[3]);
      var returnValue2 = GetArgumentValue(arguments[4]);
    
      switch (operation)
      {
         case "eq":
            output.Write(value1 == value2 ? returnValue1 : returnValue2);
            break;
         case "ne":
            output.Write(value1 != value2 ? returnValue1 : returnValue2);
            break;
         default:
            throw new Exception("ifCond: Unrecognized operation");
      }
   });
}
```

And I am using it like this:

```
'{{ifCond MyData eq 01 X Y}}'
```

**Whats the problem?**

MyData is a variable with value 01
This means that comparing MyData to 01 should print X, unfortunately, it prints Y (meaning they are not equal).
This is because all of the arguments are of type UndefinedBindingResult except the 3rd one that is integer. That is why comparing MyData (01) to 1 is not equal.

**Question:** Whats the right way to pass a string to my helper function? Obviously, it interprets the 3rd argument - 01, as an integer and provides it as just 1.

**Disclaimer:** I realize my explanation is not very good, but my Handlebards knowledge is limited.

Comment: `{{ifCond MyData eq "01" X Y}}` ?

Comment: @76484 I tried that one. It escapes the quotes and what arrives in the .NET program is something like &quote01&quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle a value as a string, just use `"`, like:

```cs
var s = "{{ifCond MyData eq \"01\" X Y}}";
```

See working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7JLLPe

---

And if you need more helpers, you can also checkout this project (which also includes the `String.Equal` helper method):

https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net.Helpers

Comment: Calling my custom function the way you describe results into arguments array having one element of type "undefined" and value quot;01&quot;

Comment: Maybe this code can help you?
https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net.Helpers/tree/master/src/Handlebars.Net.Helpers.Core/Parsers

Comment: @ValentinMezev : using the latest HandleBars and my proposed code whould work.
See https://dotnetfiddle.net/7JLLPe

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Then I should update to latest version, probably.